# Get db records from today and tomorrow in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My desired end result is that I want to group events on the events#index page by 3 time periods: Today, Tomorrow and This week. Ideally, it should be sorted by the visitor's time zone, but, the primary use case is EST if that matters.

It's just a fairly simple Rails app that you can check out here:
https://github.com/moizk/events

I'm fairly new to Rails, so I assume this sort of thing is handled by the Controller, and creating three instance variables instead of:

```
@events = Event.all
```

It should be something like:

```
@todaysevents = Events.where(some logic in here)
@tomorrowsevents = Events.where(some logic in here)
```

I just can't figure out what that logic should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding three scopes to the model, replacing `event_start_at` with whatever time field you are using:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :today, lambda { where(event_start_at: Time.zone.now.all_day }
  scope :tomorrow, lambda { where(event_start_at: 1.day.from_now.all_day }
  scope :this_week, lambda { where(event_start_at: Time.zone.now.all_week }   
end
```

And using them in the controller:

```
@events_today = Event.today
@events_tomorrow = Event.tomorrow
@events_this_week = Event.this_week
```

If you follow Sandi Metz's "one instance variable per action" rule, which I quite like, you might prefer to wrap these events in an object:

```
@events = {
  today: Event.today,
  tomorrow: Event.tomorrow,
  this_week: Event.this_week
}
```

And then use them in the view like `@events[:today]`, `@events[:tomorrow], @events[:this_week]`.

You could even wrap the hash in an OpenStruct to allow `@events.today`, `@events.tomorrow`, `@events.this_week`, but this is probably well into bike shedding territory.

Comment: So I added this to my controller:

`@events_today = Events.today`

This to my model:
`scope :today, lambda { where(event_start_date: Time.zone.now.all_day) }`

And this is the view loop:

`<% @events_today.each do |event| %>`

And the app returns the error:
`undefined method today for Events:Module`

Comment: Because I am an idiot and that should read `Event`, not `Events`. Fixing.

Comment: @MoizKhanMalik You might consider injecting the time into the scopes to make them a bit more generally useful: `scope :today, lambda {|time = Time.zone.now| where(event_start_at: time.all_day) }`. Then you could say `scope :tomorrow, lambda { today(1.day.from_now) }`.

Comment: Re: Sandi Metz's one instance per action - neat way to create a quick presenter, but isn't that just putting all the instance variables in a hash?

Comment: @Swards Yep, but encapsulation is always "just" putting related things in one place ;) and YMMV on how much value you get out of it in this instance. I thought it useful to mention but too tangential to include a full 'put it in a presenter' writeup.